# How to fetch related source and destination Flights from table

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi My table consists of:

```
source  destination
LA  BOS
LA  BOS
Seattle BOS
Bos LA
BOS Seattle
NY  Seattle
CA  LA
LA  CA
LA  Chicago
CA  BOS
BOS Seattle
```

I am trying to fetch if my source either contains boston or seattle and if either my destination contains boston or seattle.
so result should look like this:

```
source  destination
Seattle BOS
BOS Seattle
BOS Seattle
```

My query does not work:

```
select source,destination 
from dbo.flights
where source in ('BOS','Seattle') or destination in('BOS','Seattle')
```

Comment: Try AND instead of OR.

Comment: Hi @jarlh I am trying to fetch distinct flights regardless source and destination ..when there are more than 3 same source and destination my below query does not work , can you take a look at it?                                                                
    select  source,destination from(
    select source,destination, dense_rank()
    over (partition by 
    case when source>destination then source else destination end,
    case when source<destination then source else destination end
    order by source) as row_count
    from dbo.flights
    ) temp
    where row_count=1;

Comment: ask a new question instead.

Comment: @jarlh new question created : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57873409/how-to-fetch-distinct-flight-regardless-of-source-and-destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @jarlh said in a comment, use `AND` instead of `OR`:

```sql
select source,
       destination 
from   dbo.flights
where  source      in ('BOS','Seattle')
AND    destination in ('BOS','Seattle')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should work, unless you have equal source/destination values.  The explicit method is:

```
where (source = 'BOS' and destination = 'Seattle') or
      (source = 'Seattle' and destination = 'BOS')
```

Does this work?  If not, you might have hidden characters in the strings.

Oracle also supports tuples, so you can express this as:

```
where (source, destination) in ( ('BOS', 'Seattle'), ('Seattle','BOS') )
```