# How to fetch distinct flight regardless of source and destination?

Tags: sql, sql-server

My table looks like this:

```
source  destination
LA  BOS
LA  BOS
Seattle BOS
Bos LA
BOS Seattle
NY  Seattle
CA  LA
LA  CA
LA  Chicago
CA  BOS
BOS Seattle
Seattle BOS
Seattle BOS
```

My code is like this :

```
select  source,destination from(
select source,destination, dense_rank()
over (partition by 
case when source>destination then source else destination end,
case when source<destination then source else destination end
order by source) as row_count
from dbo.flights
) temp
where row_count=1;
```

result :

```
CA  BOS
Bos LA
CA  LA
LA  Chicago
BOS Seattle
BOS Seattle
NY  Seattle
NY  Seattle
NY  Seattle
```

I dont want 6th row because they are same as 5th row and also I dont want 8th and 9th because they are same as 7th.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You can just add group by source, destination to get rid of the duplicate rows.

Answer (score 1):

The original version of this question was tagged "Oracle", where you can use `least()` and `greatest()`?

```
select distinct least(source, destination), greatest(source, destination)
from t;
```

You can do the same thing in SQL Server using `case` expressions:

```
select (case when source < destination then source else destination end),
       (case when source < destination then destination else source end)
from t;
```

Comment: least() and greatest() is not applicable in sql server

Comment: @kkl . . . That's nice.  The question is tagged "oracle".

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187090/does-sql-server-support-greatest-and-least-if-not-what-is-the-common-workaround

Answer (score 0):

Group by make it works:

```
select  source,destination from(
select source,destination, dense_rank()
over (partition by 
case when source>destination then source else destination end,
case when source<destination then source else destination end
order by source) as row_count
from dbo.flights
group by source,destination
) temp
where row_count=1;
```